# Check opening hours in different timezones

Tags: postgresql, timezone

My Specs:

- Postgres 9.6.6, latest Ubuntu LTS
- Server Timezone is GMT
- A table with two columns that shows store opening and closing times, with each timezone.

Here's the table:

```
ShopId      OpenAt           CloseAt
  1      09:00:00 -08     17:00:00 -08
  2      09:30:00 -05     17:30:00 -05
  3      08:00:00 -11     15:00:00 -11
  4      10:00:00 +07     15:30:00 +07
```

What I need to know is if at moment (at my current GMT time), the shop is open. Taking into consideration that Saturday and Sunday it's closed.

I'm digging around and I got something like:

```
 SELECT ((OpenAt,CloseAt) OVERLAPS(NOW())) AND ISODOW < 6
```

with no luck...

Thanks
Perez

Comment: have you tried with  ((OpenAt,CloseAt) OVERLAPS(NOW(),NOW())) and EXTRACT (ISODOW FROM now()) <6 ?

Comment: SELECT (('09:00:00+03'::time, '17:00:00+03'::time) OVERLAPS(NOW(),NOW())) and EXTRACT (ISODOW FROM now()) <6 
 **Return:CAST ERROR**

Comment: You can't compare time and timeStamp  try this : SELECT ((date_trunc('day',now())+'09:00:00+03'::time, date_trunc('day',now())+'17:00:00+03'::time) OVERLAPS(NOW(),NOW())) and EXTRACT (ISODOW FROM now()) <6

Comment: But you can add your time to the actual day : date_trunc('day',now)+'09:00:00+03':time

Comment: It doesn't works as expected, imagine if you are in London now, you may get FALSE, but that query return TRUE : *SELECT ((date_trunc('day',now())+'09:00:00+8'::time, date_trunc('day',now())+'16:00:00+8'::time) OVERLAPS(NOW(),NOW()))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT ((date_trunc('day',nowAtShopLocation)+"OpenAt"::time, date_trunc('day',nowAtShopLocation)+"CloseAt"::time) OVERLAPS(nowAtShopLocation,nowAtShopLocation)) and EXTRACT (ISODOW FROM nowAtShopLocation) <6
from (
  select *,now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'+(EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR FROM "OpenAt")||' hour')::interval nowAtShopLocation from your_table
) a
```

Comment: Works as expected.

Comment: This seems to produce the same results, but more simple ...`SELECT (now()::time BETWEEN (OpenAt AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AND (CloseAt AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) AND EXTRACT (ISODOW FROM now()) <6 FROM MyTable`

Comment: Yes that's work at 90%, but the timezone difference can cause the current server day and the user's current day to be different. And this is not handled by your request